# Xamarin - Auto Provisioning Failing

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

My company wants me to build an app for them that works on an IPad so I obtained a new IPad, paid $148 for an account, set up and synced my laptop and IPad.

I have VS 2022 running on a Windows 10 system.  Have installed Xamarin.

It keeps giving me this message 'XCode 7.3 or later is required to keep developing with your Apple ID'

VS error is 'No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. Please enable Automatic Provisioning from the iOS Bundle Signing page' - Automatic Provisioning is already enabled.

Doing some research it appears this message indicates (quite terribly) that I don't have a paid developer account however I have logged into my account and I definitely do have one.  Under my account I am listed as Admin / Account Holder.

Any help would be appreciated.  I want to throw my Apple devices off the balcony right now.

Comment: do you have your PC paired with a Mac?  A Mac is required for any iOS/MacOS development, even with Xamarin.

Comment: Hi @Jason thanks that's what was wrong.  I went and bought a Mac but now I am confused since if I have a Mac why would I use Xamarin?

Comment: Because it’s .NET, a platform millions of devs already know how to use that doesn’t require them to learn a new language, and because it allows them to target iOS and Android with a single code base

Comment: @Jason Ahh okay makes sense.  I only ever coded for PC.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-load-apple-certificates/1692185

This is a known issue, and they are working on a fix.